# Ansible: how to consider only one of variables as mandatory when interpolating the values

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Let's assume we need to interpolate a value from one of two variables. If the first one is undefined, use the value of the second one.

```
- set_fact:
    result: >-
      var1 | default(var2)
```

Though we also can't accept that the result will be empty, so we need to make sure that at least one of `var1` or `var2` is defined (not both of them though). In this case we would be willing to do something like that:

```
- set_fact:
    result: >-
      var1 | default(var2 | mandatory)
```

It looks good, but it doesn't work. Alas, Ansible raises an exception if `var2` in not defined even if `var1` is fine. It doesn't matter whether `var1` is defined or not, Ansible just checks if `var2` defined without taking into consideration that this check is not needed if it actually isn't going to assign a default value.

Speaking frankly, as from my point of view, this `var2 | mandatory` should never be proceeded if `var1` is defined, but Ansible is not a programming language, so I understand that it works another way.

The only idea I have is to make sure that one of variables is defined *beforehand*, so it looks as follows:

```
- assert:
    that:
      - (var1 | mandatory) or (var2 | mandatory)

- set_fact:
    result: >-
      var1 | default(var2)
```

Although I don't like that, because of 2 reasons, here they are.

1. I have to add a whole additional step (`assert`).
2. I don't like that `var2` is not being checked in the `set_fact` step. Of course, Ansible checks them on the previous step, but it still *looks like* `result` might get the `null` value, which is undesired. Even if it only *looks like* that it still irritates me a little.

What I would like is to find some alternative to the `mandatory` filter, but I need this "quasi-`mandatory`" to be considered only if `var1` is undefined.

Is there a way to solve it with some short and neat idiom instead of these 2 steps? Something like `$var1 // $var2 // any_way_to_raise_an_exception('Neither $var1 nor #var2 is defined, accept our condolences');` in Perl. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the cases I tried, it works with an outer set of parens, and I also found that `mandatory` accepts an undocumented message for when it dies

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: the value is {{ ((var1|default(var2))|mandatory("need var1 or var2") }}
```

and gives precedence to `var1`, uses `var2` if provided, and dies with `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "need var1 or var2"}` if neither are

Answer (score 1):

Sidenote: It's possible to declare a *default* value if both *var1* and *var2* are not defined. For example,

```yaml
result: "{{ var1|default(var2)|default('default') }}"
```

But, the use-case of the question is: Fail if both *var1* and *var2* are not defined.

---

Q: ***"Can't accept that the result will be empty, so we need to make sure  that at least one of var1 or var2 is defined."***

A: *assert* does not work the way you expect. It will fail if *var1* is not defined. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: var1
    - debug:
        var: var2
    - assert:
        that: var1|mandatory or var2|mandatory
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  var1: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  var2: test

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: 'The conditional check ''(var1|mandatory) or (var2|mandatory)'' failed. The error was: Mandatory variable ''var1''  not defined.'
```

Instead, the task below does what you want

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: (var1|default('')|length > 0) or
              (var2|default('')|length > 0)
```

---

Q: ***"Short and neat idiom instead of 2 steps? Something like `exception('Neither $var1 nor #var2 is defined')`."***

A: Actually, the *default* filter does it. The exception below says: `'var2' is undefined`. (We know that *var2* is needed only if *var1* is undefined. Why repeat it?)

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: var1
    - debug:
        var: var2
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ var1|default(var2) }}"
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  var1: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  var2: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'var2' is undefined
```

Comment: I have to use the `default()` filter for `var2`, because in my case  `var2` is not just a variable, but a parameter of a dictionary (let's call it `dict.var2`). The funny thing is that `var2` key might be absent in the `dict` dictionary. If it's absent then Ansible fails, even if `var1` is fine. That's why I need the `default()` filter for `var2` as well. ;-(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your unnecessary introduction of `mandatory`. Ansible's behaviour is correct without this, unless you've (very unwisely) disabled [`error_on_undefined_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-undefined-var-behavior)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    foo: eh
    bar: bee
  tasks:
    # foo is set, so we get its value
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo | default(bar) }}"

    # baz is not set, so we get bar
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ baz | default(bar) }}"

    # foo is set, so we get its value
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo | default(quux) }}"

    # neither baz nor quux is set, so we get an error
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ baz | default(quux) }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "eh"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "bee"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "eh"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'quux' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/test.yml': line 20, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    # neither baz nor quux is set, so we get an error\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

If you *have* disabled `error_on_undefined_vars`, you should use `mandatory` as the final filter, instead of putting it on a non-mandatory value:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ baz | default(quux) | mandatory }}"
```

Or, if you require that one and exactly one value be set, there's no way around using `assert` (because you're imposing a non-standard requirement), but you should use the `defined` test, not the `mandatory` filter.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    foo: eh
    bar: bee
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: "[foo, baz] | select('defined') | length == 1"

    - assert:
        that: "[foo, bar] | select('defined') | length == 1"
      ignore_errors: true

    - assert:
        that: "[baz, quux] | select('defined') | length == 1"
```

```
TASK [assert] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [assert] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "[foo, bar] | select('defined') | length == 1",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}
...ignoring

TASK [assert] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "[baz, quux] | select('defined') | length == 1",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}
```